# Basis Transformation Matrix Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $\beta$ and $\beta'$ be bases for the finite dimensional vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ over the field $\mathbb F$, and let $Q = [I_V]_{\beta'}^{\beta}$, where $I_V$ is the identity operator on $V$. I just recently proved that $Q[x]_{\beta'} = [x]_{\beta}$ for every $x \in V$ (twas rather simple), which suggests the title of "basis transformation" matrix or "coordinate transformation" matrix for the matrix $Q$. I am now wondering whether the converse holds.

Let $V'$ denote $V$ with its elements written with respect to the basis $\beta'$, and suppose that $Q \in M_n(\mathbb F)$ is such that $Q[x]_{\beta'} = [x]_{\beta}$ for every $x$. Since $\mathcal{L}(V'V)$ is isomorphic to the matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb F)$ by sending a linear operator to its matrix representation, given $Q$ there exists a linear operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(V',V)$ such that $Q=[T]_{\beta'}^{\beta}$. Hence $[T]_{\beta'}^{\beta} [x]_{\beta'} = [x]_{\beta}$ or $[T(x)]_{\beta} = [x]_{\beta}$...

I want to say that this implies $T=I_V$, but I can't clearly see what lemma I need in order to make that conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation $[T(x)]_\beta=[x]_\beta$ says that $T(x)$ and $x$ have the same coordinates in the basis $\beta$. This means they can be written as the same linear combination of vectors of $\beta$ and thus $T(x)=x$ for all $x\in V$, i.e. $T=I_V$.